# on change event in ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I have a small problem coming with on change event in jQuery. Basically I'm sending one request to servlet using Ajax and getting a map from servlet. I need to show only those records to user when user will enter date in date textbox. Validation (match the date from textbox and hashmap coming from servlet) for date I'm doing in Ajax only. That is happening well, but the table is not being displayed. Could anybody help me? Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datetextboxid').on('change',function(){
    var val=$('#datetextboxid').val();  
        $.ajax({
            url : 'T_Oms_08_D_Delivery_Servlet',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(json) {
                var dateTableRow = "";
                var headerOfTable="";                       
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    if(value.date==val){
                        dateTableRow=dateTableRow
                        +"<tr bgcolor='#F0F8FF'>"
                        +"<td>" + value.omsOrderId+ "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.orderId+ "</td>"
                        +"<td>" + value.customerId+ "</td>"
                        +"</tr>";
                    }
                });
                headerOfTable=headerOfTable
                + "<tr bgcolor='#6495ED'>"
                +"<td>Order DB ID</td>"
                +"<td>Order ID</td>"
                +"<td>Customer ID</td>" 
                +"</tr>";
                $("#form").html(headerOfTable+dateTableRow).fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(1000);
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                for (key in xhr)
                    console.log(key + ":" + xhr[key]);
            },
            complete : function(xhr, status) {
                //alert("The request is complete!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

script for datetextbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datedropdown').datepicker({         
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
            constrainInput: false 
    });
});
```

table body tag

```
<body>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="1" style="empty-cells: hide;" width="7800" >
<tbody id="form">   
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are your opening and closing tags for your table? `<table></table>`

Comment: you don't close the `tr` elements, in the header you should have `th` instead of `td`. As @RickBronger said you should wrap your code into `table` element

Comment: yes i forgot to put that i was putting that but mistakenly post gets submitted..i m editing this post again..wait

Comment: Can you add the generated html of the table (after the success execution) to your post? (inspect your page with chrome or something else)

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://jsfiddle.net/7a58txnt/ - type in input `2016/03/03` or `2016/03/04` or `2016/03/05`.

Comment: I would like to tell you guys as i solved my problem so no need to answer this question..It was date format issue..thats it..code is running well...

Comment: @ofca thanks for the hint..

Comment: Always glad to help.